# Who was in the cantina band in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

When Han and company walked into Maz's cantina style bar, I was really hoping to see these guys from Episode IV playing:

[image]

But sadly, it was a different band - who were they?

Comment: Well it has been 30 years, I'd guess the boys split up. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Visual Dictionary* (page 73) covers it in detail:

The band members are Taybin Ralorsa, Infrablue Zedbeddy Coggins, Ubert "Sticks" Quaril, and Sudswater Dillifay Glon.

No, I didn't make the names up. Here's proof:

[image]

Visual dictionary doesn't offer many (or any :) details on them, except that they don't seem to be a permanent house band.

Side notes:

- The band you hoping to find was called [Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Figrin_D'an_and_the_Modal_Nodes), all 7 members were Bith.
- In a sweet and delicious symmetry to those of us suffering from the overabundance of OCD, the band from Episode IV had 7 players, while the band from Episode VII had 4 players.
- According to V.D.'s author, Pablo Hidalgo's twitter, the names are meant to be "blues" invoking and he's quite proud of them.

Comment: Note: as of yet, according to all I know, the band has no name. Therefore, I'm dubbing them Sound Makers, in honour of XKCD.

Comment: @randal'thor - TY. Not as good as [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111978/976) or [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113734/976) or [this](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113720/976) :)  Those were my favorite, if you don't count Bingo and Obi1 lies.

Comment: I should probably nominate some more of yours on my answer to "Best of 4th Quarter 2015" on meta. It's so hard to pick out just a few though!

Comment: Still not good as good as "Elan Sleazebaggano" the drug dealer.

Comment: Any chance the Max Rebo band had six players? Nope, those Jizz Wailers were only three in number, although in the special addition there were 12! (2x6, perhaps?)